# w3c validator give error on image mapping for HTML 4.01 Strict

Tags: html, css

Hi Everyone,
            i am try to use the image mapping in HTML 4.01 Strict,but the w3c validoter give me the error of map not supporting,
my code is look like this

```
<img id="link_image" src="images/livechat.png" usemap="#Map" alt="The chat link" />
<map name="Map" id="Map" class="newWindow link-chat" ><area shape="rect"  coords="79,3,521,67" href="#" alt="The chat link mapping" /></map>
```

Give the following error,

```
Line 57, Column 54: document type does not allow element "MAP" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "PRE", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag
```

Comment: The W3C validation service will not give an error "map not supporting". It might help if you quoted the actual error message you were getting.

Comment: i add the error message there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map cannot be placed inside the body tag, place it inside div instead (or one of the alternatives in the error message), like so:

```
<div>
    <img id="link_image" src="images/livechat.png" usemap="#Map" alt="The chat link" /
    <map name="Map" id="Map" class="newWindow link-chat" ><area shape="rect"  coords="79,3,521,67" href="#" alt="The chat link mapping"></map>
</div>
```

You also need to remove the unnecessary map short tag as previously suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spurious “/” characters (before “>”) or change your document to use XHTML, where they are allowed (and required).

Technically the issue is that by the SGML rules, “/” terminates the tag and the “>” character is then content data, which is diasllowed inside a `map` element. And by asking for HTML 4.01 validation, you are asking for the SGML rules to apply (even though browsers don’t apply them).

The validator first issues the warning message “NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES”, which is admittedly cryptic, but it is a clue to understanding what really happens. The full story, to those interested in the theory, is in [Empty elements in SGML, HTML, XML, and XHTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html).

Answer (score 0):

An error for sure is due to the presence of both `/` at the end of `<map>` opening tag and the closing `</map>` tag placed after.